# How to avoid / suppress JSF <h:selectOneMenu /> null (no selection option) tab?

Tags: java, jsf

When creating a new item the user does not want to see the null no selection option in the Select-One Menu, but directly an item from the available items. So either to get rid of the null no option or display directly the second element in the dropdown. I tried the attribute `hideNoSelection`, but it does nothing.
How can I achieve this?

```
<h:selectOneMenu id="ugroup" value="#{usersController.selected.ugroup}" title="#{bundle.CreateUsersTitle_ugroup}" required="true" requiredMessage="#{bundle.CreateUsersRequiredMessage_ugroup}">
```

```
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

----------------EDIT (after @Balus Answer) ---------------------
Here is the Utility method that grabs JPA Lists to be displayed as a `<h:selectOneMenu />` :

```
public class JsfUtil {

    public static SelectItem[] getSelectItems(List<?> entities, boolean selectOne) {
        int size = selectOne ? entities.size() + 1 : entities.size();
        SelectItem[] items = new SelectItem[size];
        int i = 0;
        if (selectOne) { // part to be removed
            items[0] = new SelectItem("", "---");
            i++;
        } // end of part to be removed
        for (Object x : entities) {
            items[i++] = new SelectItem(x, x.toString());
        }
        return items;
    }
```

So appearently, all I have to do is remove this part? :

```
 if (selectOne) {
                items[0] = new SelectItem("", "---");
                i++;
            }
```

But as this static method is used everywhere in my code, would it have any unwanted consequences?

- Like, when the user wants explicitly a null value from the **`<h:selectOneMenu />`**, if he decides to choose no option. My guess was to use **`<f:selectItem`**  :

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just ensure that `#{ugroupController.itemsAvailableSelectOne}` does not contain an item with value `null` in the array or list. The first item will be the default selected option.

Alternatively, preset the property behind `#{usersController.selected.ugroup}` with the value of the desired item during bean's (post)construction.

Comment: thanks @BalusC for the quick answer! I edited my question! I just need to know if it is safe to do the modification above to pass to modify the code!

Comment: You can do so. Note that since JSF 2.0, the `<f:selectItems>` does not explicitly require a `SelectItem[]` or `List<SelectItem>` (or `Map<K, V>`) anymore. A `List<Entity>` is also perfectly fine.

Comment: didn't know that at all! That might help me achieve other things so :) like adding a list to an object easily.... Ok much humble thanks again @BalusC.

Comment: You're welcome. Note the `var` attribute. It serves the same purpose as in `<ui:repeat>` and `<c:forEach>`.